# detect content of iframe change , the content is dynamic (jQuery mobile)

Tags: jquery, html

Okay , I have a jQuery mobile enabled page loaded inside an iFrame.

Normally if i want to detect iframe content change i use :

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
   //content changed!
});
```

But in this case its different , this iframe loaded up a page which has jQuery mobile enabled (its a mobile site). 
jQuery mobile fetches the html data using ajax from the server. then change the content of the page without reloading. I think its called dynamic content.

NOTE: The domain of the page inside iframe is same with the parent window domain.

How would I detect this iframe content change then?

Comment: JQM uses $(document).on("pagechange",function(){ //Code }); to keep track when it loads a new page in with ajax, but I don't know if you can run it in your parent domain without problems.

Comment: Hi , can I do like `$('iframe').contents().on("pagechange",function(){ //Code });`

Comment: Never worked with a iframe opening a page with JQM, so I dont know, feel free to try! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Untested but there you have the ajaxStart and ajaxComplete method, which fires, you could try:

```
$('#iframe').bind('load',function(){
    var instance = this.contentWindow.jQuery,
        doc = this.contentWindow.document;

    instance(doc).ajaxStart(function(){console.log('ajaxStart');});
    instance(doc).ajaxComplete(function(){console.log('ajaxComplete');});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **dont** wanna use the jQuery old **"bind"**, try:

```
$('#my-iframe-id').load(function(){

    var instance = this.contentWindow.jQuery,
    doc = this.contentWindow.document;

    instance(doc).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('ajaxStart');
    });
    instance(doc).ajaxStop(function(){
        console.log('ajaxStop');
        // This is the place to check or compare window heights = changed content
    });
    instance(doc).ajaxComplete(function(){
        console.log('ajaxComplete');
    });

});
```